# Characterization of contraction mapping

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems

Let $T$ be a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

Fix $x^\star \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and suppose that the Jacobian matrix of $T(x) $ at $x = x^\star$is symmetric.

Then, I know that if all the eigenvales of the Jacobain of $T$ at $x = x^\star$ have absolute values less than 1, then $T$ is a (local) contraction at $x = x^\star$.

But, is the converse true?  Is it necessary for $T$ to have all the eigenvalues of its Jacobain less than 1 in absolute value for $T$ to be a local contraction?

Comment: Do you define contraction by a Lipschitz constant $< 1$ or $\le 1$? Btw. the codomain of $T$ should be $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @user251257 I define a contraction by strict inequality $<$. I fixed the codomain.

Comment: Because $\max|\lambda|=\|T(x^*)\|$ and because the constant $L=\|T(x^*)\|$ is the smallest constant, such that $\|T(x^*)(y)\|\leq L \|y\|$, I think that it is necessary that all the eigenvalues are less than 1 in absolute value.

Comment: My argument works if we want the map $T(x^*)$ to be a contraction on the whole space $\mathbb R^n$, i.e for each $y\in \mathbb R^n:\,\, \|T(x^*)(y)\|\leq L \|y\|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly true, if $T'$ is continuous at $x^*$.

Assume $T$ admits a Lipschitz constant $L<1$ w.r.t the norm $\|\cdot\|$ on a neighborhood $U$ of $x^*$.
Let $h$ such that $\|h\|=1$ and $\| T'(x^*)h \| = \| T'(x^*) \|$.
Then, for $t > 0$ and sufficiently small, by mean value theorem, we have some $\tau\in(0,t)$ such that
$$ 1 > L \ge \frac{\|T(x^* + th) - T(x^*)\|}{\|th\|} = \left\| T'(x^* + \tau h)h \right\| \to \| T'(x^*)h \| $$
for $t\to 0$.

Now, as the spectral radius is a lower bound for any operator norm, we proved the claim.

Comment: How do you know such $h$ exists?

Comment: @pm021 because the vector space is finite dimensional.

Comment: @pm021 the operator norm is defined by $\|T'(x^*)\| = \sup_{\|h\|=1} \|T'(x^*)h\|$. As the vector space is finite dimensional, the sphere is compact and the supremum is attained.