# $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a contraction mapping $\iff$ spectral radius of Jacobian is less than one

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-operator

In a previous class, we used the following theorem without proof:

> *Theorem*: Let $f:(\mathbb{R}^n,|\cdot|)\to(\mathbb{R}^n,|\cdot|)$ be differentiable, where $|\cdot|$ denotes the Euclidean norm. Suppose that the spectral radius of the Jacobian of $f$ is less than one on some subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $f$ is a contraction mapping on $U$.

With a bit more analysis background than I had when this theorem was originally presented to me, I have been trying to prove this, but have gotten stuck. I have proved what I believe to be a necessary step (reminiscent of that used in the proof for the case $n=1$), where if $\Vert Df\Vert\leq K$ on an open convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $f$ is Lipschitz on that subset with Lipschitz constant $K$. However, I am stuck now on showing that $f$ is a contraction mapping.

I have seen similar propositions where if $Df$ is symmetric on $U$, then $f$ is a contraction mapping - the proof quickly follows in this case, as then the operator norm $\Vert Df(x)\Vert$ is equal to the spectral radius of $Df(x)$. However, in general this is not the case, and I haven't been able to figure out where to go in the general case - or if the theorem is even true without that assumption.

My question - are the conditions that I have placed on $Df$ and $U$ in the above theorem sufficient? Or are there more necessary conditions necessary? (Likely, we need $U$ to be convex in order to apply the lemma I have proved.) If $Df$ is not required to be symmetric / if there are no more conditions required on $Df$ for $f$ to be a contraction mapping, what might be the first step to take in the proof?

Comment: The theorem you mention requires some clarification, otherwise it does not hold. $f$ is a contraction mapping for which norm? The spectral radius is a lower bound for any matrix norm, and if the spectral radius of the Jacobian is less then 1, $f$ will be contractive in some norm, not in  all norms.

Comment: @PierreCarre I have edited the question to include that the standard Euclidean norm is being used - we can take the matrix norm to be the operator norm induced from the Euclidean vector norm.

Comment: Right, the point is that if the spectral radius is less than 1 then the operator norm can still exceed 1 in some vector norms, just not all of them. Consider the simple example $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 10 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, with spectral radius 0 and Euclidean operator norm 10.

Comment: @Ian I am familiar with that example. So in which norms is the spectral radius being less than one sufficient to guarantee that the matrix norm is also less than one? I haven't been able to find any information on that

Comment: Not in the Euclidean norm in particular, no. It will be contractive in some norm, though.

Comment: @csch2 If your point is to prove convergence of some fixed point method, you should take into account that all norms over $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent. If the spectral norm is less then 1, the fixed point will be convergent for any norm (even if $f$ is not contractive).

Comment: @PierreCarre But then you wouldnt know if that norm is consistent (which applies to induced norms, but not to all matrix norms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct statement should be : $f$  if Lipschitz with constant $K$ (for some norms on $\mathbb{R}^m$, $\mathbb{R}^n$)  if and only if the norm of the Jacobian matrix is $\le K$.  Considering a map from a space with a norm to itself, the induced norm of the Jacobian ( or of any square matrix) is $\ge $ spectral radius.  And it can be $>$. Hence, using the spectral radius is not good enough in one sense, unless you have some special cases, say the matrix being selfadjoint, and the norm being the one induced from the euclidian metric.

Comment: I suppose I am confused because I have found several sources (such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378399/characterization-of-contraction-mapping)) where the eigenvalues being less than one implies $f$ being a contraction mapping. Is this wrong?

Comment: @csch2:  the linked sourced assumes a symmetric jacobian. But not true in general.